# How to open smile file

Tags: python

I want to export some data to an app that is installed on my mobile phone. So I exported some dummy data in the app, in order to investigate how I can produce data to import.

First step: It's a gzipped file. No problem, that is what gunzip is for.

Second step:

```
$ file export
export: Smile binary data version 0: binary encoded, shared String values disabled, shared field names
```

I have never heard of a smile file (which is quite ugly to google because of the emoticons), but I found pySmile. Problem: I am not even a noob regarding python. To be more specific: I don't know anything about python.

But I tried it anyways.

```
import pysmile
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
a = f.read()
print repr(a)
o=pysmile.decode(a)
print o
```

This worked pretty well with a smile file I generated myself, but with the given export smile file I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dec.py", line 7, in <module>
    o=pysmile.decode(a)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysmile/decode.py", line 224, in decode
    state.copy_shared_value_string()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysmile/decode.py", line 151, in copy_shared_value_string
    raise SMILEDecodeError('Cannot lookup shared value, sharing disabled!')
pysmile.decode.SMILEDecodeError: Cannot lookup shared value, sharing disabled!
```

After that I tried to investigate where the difference between the two files is:

```
export: Smile binary data version 0: binary encoded, shared String values disabled, shared field names enabled
dummyf: Smile binary data version 0: binary encoded, shared String values enabled, shared field names enabled
```

This in addition to the Error Trace lead me to my question: How can I enable sharing in pysmile (decode and encode), and is there another python-free method to convert a smile file to a text file and (which is even more important) the other way around?